# OpenLDAP how to add policy: Password must differ in at least 2 characters from previous password?

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, password-policy

I am trying to implement a password policy in OpenLDAP.

So far this is how my LDIF looks like for it:

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changeType: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: ppolicy

dn: olcOverlay=ppolicy,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcPpolicyConfig
olcOverlay: ppolicy
olcPPolicyDefault: cn=ppolicy,dc=ldaptuto,dc=net
olcPPolicyUseLockout: FALSE
olcPPolicyHashCleartext: TRUE

dn: cn=ppolicy,dc=ldaptuto,dc=net
objectClass: device
objectClass: pwdPolicyChecker
objectClass: pwdPolicy
cn: ppolicy
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdMinLength: 10
pwdCheckQuality: 1
pwdInHistory: 5
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdMaxAge: 7776000
pwdMaxFailure: 10
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 1800
```

I need to make sure that when the user changes their password the new one differs in at least 2 positions from the old password.

I did not find any policy setting in the LDAP wiki for this. I also tried searching on the web with no result.

I figured I could write my own password checker, something like [this](https://github.com/onyxpoint/ppolicy-check-password/blob/master/check_password.c), however, I don't see the old password being used in the checking process.

How can I implement a policy that ensures the new password differs in at least 2 positions from the old one in OpenLDAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to

1. set `pwdSafeModify: TRUE` in *pwdPolicy* entry
2. always change the password with Password Modify extended operation (see [RFC 3062](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3062)) also sending along the old user password (see ASN.1 field *oldPasswd*)

Then your own pwdChecker module also receives the old password when processing the extended operation request.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implement my own checker.